# rational egoism

Tags: ethics

Which of the following correctly expresses the theory called "Rational Egoism"?
A.  All human actions are ultimately motivated by self-interested reasons.

B.  Whether or not we can act solely in the interest of others, we never should act solely in the interest of others.
C.  Genuine altruism, wherein one's action is sufficiently motivated by altruistic reasons, is psychologically impossible.

D.  A and C

Comment: Hi, welcome to Philosophy SE. Please visit our [Help Center](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help) to see what questions we answer and how to ask. We only answer HW/test questions when they show research effort and describe specific difficulties. Please describe your thinking on this issue and what seems to stump you. General descriptions of rational egoism are available from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_egoism), [IEP](http://www.iep.utm.edu/egoism/#SH2a) and [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/egoism/#3).

Comment: B. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_egoism because then we should always act in our self interest

Comment: I'm voting tohome close this question as off-topic because it's a homework question

Answer (score 2):

None of the above. It's E: it's rational to act only in one's own interest, and it's irrational to act only in the interest of others. Since rational is not exactly equivalent to what you ought to do, this is distinct from B (but it could imply B).

Comment: but "rational egoism" is a thesis about what we ought to do, right?

Comment: We ought to do something either because it is rational or because it is moral, but something can be rational without being moral. So one could subscribe to B: you ought to be selfish for moral reasons, without subscribing to D.

Comment: It's just that "ought" is more general than "rational"

Comment: yes, but "rational egoism" is a thesis about what we ought to do, it's not the same as any combination of the terns "rational" and "egoism"

Comment: Something rational is something we ought to do on the basis of reason, so yes, it's a thesis about what we ought to do, but in a limited sense.

Comment: i think (THINK) you're still misunderstanding me. "rational egoism" is a philosophical thesis, which says that we ought (OUGHT) to act in our own interests, at all times. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_egoism seems, and i'm not at all sure now, that you are posting based on the meaning of the individual terms, rather than their parlance in philosophy when run together, which the wikipedia page documents

Comment: The Wikipedia page you're linking to says that rational egoism is distinct from ethical egoism which says that we ought to act in our own interest https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethical_egoism

Comment: Arguably, reason constraints moral but as I said, something can be rational but not moral (nor immoral, just amoral).

Comment: I think you misread the Wikipedia article

Comment: eh i didn't read past the 1st line, sorry.

Comment: but anyway, i'm still right, the question does imply B. you can say it implies other stuff too, but every doctrine known to man does more than can be summated in a single line in a multiple choice exam

Comment: doesn't rational egoism trivially imply ethical egoism? and apologies, i was just completely unaware that someone would ever bother claiming one and not the other. why say the latter and not the former? how could i be rationally obliged to be selfish but not so as to act on that in rational ways? seems incoherent, like claiming i'm rationally obliged to save the drowning child but not rationally obliged to remember how to swim. not trivial, but not meaningful either

Comment: I agree that it probably implies B. I'm not a specialist of the issue but I guess rational egoism is a stronger thesis than mere ethical egoism: it holds that 1/ our ethics should be based on reason only (and not on a notion of good that would be independent of what is rational) and 2/ that reason tells us to be egoist. So one could be an ethical egoist without resorting to reason for its justification.

Comment: I found more details here if you're interested https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/egoism/#2